# UPS behaviour when Snow Leopard is asleep

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, sleep, ups

What is Snow Leopard's behaviour when there is a power failure and it is connected to a UPS, and it is in sleep mode? Will the UPS alarm notification wake OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change on the USB bus should trigger a wake from sleep, so that the system can see what has happened...  (For example, place your system to sleep, and then plug in a USB mouse.  Your system should wake up...)

So, yes, as long as your UPS will announce a state change, it should be detected.

Comment: I've tried it with my UPS (APC Back-UPS E700) and Mac Pro (2008) I can confirm it does wake the Mac Pro on a power failure when the Mac Pro is asleep.